# rsync only files and not directories

Tags: rsync

I wish to sync my portable with my Maemo smartphone for just the files in my working directory (top level folder). What can I do to correct my rsync command to sync files in the source folder but not directories?

```
rsync -va --no-r --no-R --no-d /home/Xtian/ /run/media/486D-8336/
skipping directory.
sent 10 bytes  received 12 bytes  44.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

The command begins with verbose and archive options as default. Then I attempted to turn off recursive, relative, and directories. In other words don't follow the tree, don't copy the tree, in fact don't even bother with the folders.

Answer (score 6):

I would try this:

```
rsync -vt /home/Xtian/* /run/media/486D-8336/
```

This will skip non regular files and enables just the timestamps on files in order to sync only the differences the next time you run it.

From `man rsync`: `-a` flag is an alias for `-rlptgoD`. You can add additional flags if you need to preserve other file attributes.

Comment: You would need the `--no-r --no-R --no-d` options also to do what the op is asking. Personally I find the `-a` flag useful, but `-t` will suffice to be efficient.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
rsync -r --exclude='*/' source/ destination/
```

Source: https://lists.samba.org/archive/rsync/2008-September/021746.html

Comment: I believe that will copy files in sub-folders if those folders exist in destination/